# Confusion regarding solution of a problem of conducting spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, conductors

> Two conducting spheres of radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ are connected by a metallic spring of stiffness $k$ and natural length $ l \gg r_1, r_2$. A positive charge $+Q$ is slowly delivered to any sphere. Find the charge on each sphere.
> [image]

The solution goes like this:
[image]

But for writing potential of each sphere, why is the potential due the other not taken into account? I can't find a good reason. Please help.

Comment: I may be wrong but i think since the spheres and the spring are all metallic, the surface of the whole system (including the spheres and the spring ) forms an equipotential surface which is why $V_1=V_2$. It is one of the properties of metals if I am not wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $l \gg r_1, r_2 $, the other sphere's potential contribution is significantly smaller than the contribution from the main sphere and thus could be approximated to zero. (Coulomb potential is inversely proportional to the distance.)

Comment: to ignore it there seperation must be large but why we are comparing it with r1 and r2 we should just say it is very large

Comment: If you write down the ratio between the potential contributions from each sphere, you'll see that it's not the absolute magnitude, but the relative magnitude of length scales is that matters.

Comment: You mean potential due to sphere itself >>>>> than potential due to other?

Comment: Yes, it's right.

Comment: Please add this point to your answer so i can approve it